# CommandTable Cystal Report Error

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that was written using a complex SQL and I'm trying to invoke that using the Crystal Report Java API. This report has a Command object associated with it.

1. I load the report and set the connection parameters.
2. Then I try to set the Connection information to the current JDBC Profile. Meaning Test Environment credentials.

I get an exception. I tried with Version 11. Version 12 both. None of them seems to be working.

I'm getting the exception when I invoke the following piece of code. This piece of code works just fine with reports without "Command" sqls.

```
try{
    clientDoc.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(
    origTable, newTable);
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

See below for the entire code. Please reply if anyone knows how to work around this.

```
private static void changeDataSource(ReportClientDocument clientDoc,
        String reportName, String tableName, String username,
        String password, String connectionURL, String driverName,
        String jndiName) throws ReportSDKException {

    PropertyBag propertyBag = null;
    IConnectionInfo connectionInfo = null;
    ITable origTable = null;
    ITable newTable = null;

    // Declare variables to hold ConnectionInfo values.
    // Below is the list of values required to switch to use a JDBC/JNDI
    // connection
    String TRUSTED_CONNECTION = "false";
    String SERVER_TYPE = "JDBC (JNDI)";
    String USE_JDBC = "true";
    String DATABASE_DLL = "crdb_jdbc.dll";
    String JNDI_OPTIONAL_NAME = jndiName;
    String CONNECTION_URL = connectionURL;
    String DATABASE_CLASS_NAME = driverName;

    // Declare variables to hold database User Name and Password values
    String DB_USER_NAME = username;
    String DB_PASSWORD = password;
    System.out.println("Trusted_Connection:" + TRUSTED_CONNECTION);
    System.out.println("Server Type:" + SERVER_TYPE);
    System.out.println("Use JDBC:" + USE_JDBC);
    System.out.println("Database DLL:" + DATABASE_DLL);
    System.out.println("JNDIOptionalName:" + JNDI_OPTIONAL_NAME);
    System.out.println("Connection URL:" + CONNECTION_URL);
    System.out.println("Database Class Name:" + DATABASE_CLASS_NAME);
    System.out.println("DB_USER_NAME:" + DB_USER_NAME);
    System.out.println("DB_PASSWORD:" + DB_PASSWORD);
    // Obtain collection of tables from this database controller
    if (reportName == null || reportName.equals("")) {
        Tables tables = clientDoc.getDatabaseController().getDatabase()
                .getTables();
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
            origTable = tables.getTable(i);

            if (tableName == null || origTable.getName().equals(tableName)) {
                newTable = (ITable) origTable;
                newTable.setQualifiedName(origTable.getAlias());
                connectionInfo = newTable.getConnectionInfo();

                // Set new table connection property attributes
                propertyBag = new PropertyBag();
                // Overwrite any existing properties with updated values
                propertyBag.put("Trusted_Connection", TRUSTED_CONNECTION);
                propertyBag.put("Server Type", SERVER_TYPE);
                propertyBag.put("Use JDBC", USE_JDBC);
                propertyBag.put("Database DLL", DATABASE_DLL);
                propertyBag.put("JNDIOptionalName", JNDI_OPTIONAL_NAME);
                propertyBag.put("Connection URL", CONNECTION_URL);
                propertyBag.put("Database Class Name", DATABASE_CLASS_NAME);
                connectionInfo.setAttributes(propertyBag);
                connectionInfo.setUserName(DB_USER_NAME);
                connectionInfo.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

                // Update the table information
                try{
                    clientDoc.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(
                        origTable, newTable);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Next loop through all the subreports and pass in the same
    // information. You may consider
    // creating a separate method which accepts
    if (reportName == null || !(reportName.equals(""))) {
        IStrings subNames = clientDoc.getSubreportController()
                .getSubreportNames();
        for (int subNum = 0; subNum < subNames.size(); subNum++) {
            Tables tables = clientDoc.getSubreportController()
                    .getSubreport(subNames.getString(subNum))
                    .getDatabaseController().getDatabase().getTables();
            for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
                origTable = tables.getTable(i);
                if (tableName == null
                        || origTable.getName().equals(tableName)) {
                    newTable = (ITable) origTable;

                    newTable.setQualifiedName(origTable.getAlias());
                    // Change connection information properties
                    connectionInfo = newTable.getConnectionInfo();
                    // Set new table connection property attributes
                    propertyBag = new PropertyBag();

                    // Overwrite any existing properties with updated values
                    propertyBag.put("Trusted_Connection",
                            TRUSTED_CONNECTION);
                    propertyBag.put("Server Type", SERVER_TYPE);
                    propertyBag.put("Use JDBC", USE_JDBC);
                    propertyBag.put("Database DLL", DATABASE_DLL);
                    propertyBag.put("JNDIOptionalName", JNDI_OPTIONAL_NAME);
                    propertyBag.put("Connection URL", CONNECTION_URL);
                    propertyBag.put("Database Class Name",
                            DATABASE_CLASS_NAME);
                    connectionInfo.setAttributes(propertyBag);
                    connectionInfo.setUserName(DB_USER_NAME);
                    connectionInfo.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

                    // Update the table information
                    clientDoc.getSubreportController()
                            .getSubreport(subNames.getString(subNum))
                            .getDatabaseController()
                            .setTableLocation(origTable, newTable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thing I forgot to mention here was, this report was originally created using an ODBC Connection and That caused it. I regenerated the report using a JDBC Connection from the scratch and it works just fine. There is nothing wrong with the CRJava API. Sorry for the confusion and hope this will help someone figure this out.

Comment: do you mean you removed setTableLocation part because you are already connected with correct DB info? Or you are still using setTableLocation part, but it works now because it is already defined for JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

Add after this line of yours

```
connectionInfo.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD); 
newTable.setConnectionInfo(connectionInfo);
//This will add connection parameters to the new table
```

Instead of

```
clientDoc.getDatabaseController().setTableLocation(origTable, newTable);
```

replace this with

```
clientDoc.getDatabaseController ().setTableLocation (newTable,  tables.getTable(i));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how it will help? Since `origTable = tables.getTable(i);` in the first place, do you say that `setTableLocation` method has reversed new and old table parameters? Otherwise you are replacing nothing so of course it does not fail.